# Completion of a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x \neq 0 \neq y$ and $d(0,x)=1+|x|$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}_{0}$ and $d(0,0)=0$.

I figure this metric space is not complete, since we can take the Cauchy sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ with $x_{n}= \frac{1}{n}$. Then for $\epsilon >0$ we can find a $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for $n,m \geq n_{0}$ it holds that $d(x_{n},x_{m})=|\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}| < \epsilon$ since $\frac{1}{n} \neq 0 \neq \frac{1}{m}$. But $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(x_{n},x_{m})=d(0,x_{m})=1+ \frac{1}{m}$ and this converges to $1$, while $\frac{1}{m} \rightarrow 0$ and $d(0,0)=0$. Thus the Cauchy sequence has no limit.

Is this correct? And if so, how should I find a completion of this metric space?

Comment: To prove that it isn't complete you should show that $\frac{1}{n}$ cannot converge to a nonzero real, and cannot converge to $0$. Have you checked that $d$ was a distance ?

Comment: The way you defined your metric would give $d(0,0) = 1 \neq 0$, contradicting the definition of a metric. So I think there is something wrong with the statement of the problem at the moment.

Comment: I was given this metric so I think it is well-defined. :) Also, $d(0,0)=0$ here because $d(0,x)=1+|x|$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}_{0}=\mathbb{R} \backslash { \{ 0 \}}$, I'll adjust it in my question.

Comment: I have checked now that $d$ is a distance.